# How can I create a notes column in a document?

Tags: packages, marginpar, notes

I need a document that has a notes column on the right hand side of each page starting after the contents page.

This notes column should have the heading "Notes" , should be 50% of the size of the main column and be separated with a thin line.

Any ideas which packages I can use to do this? I've managed to get a wide ruled margin. No heading so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get you started. I extended the size of the margin and used `\marginpar` to place the text in the margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\setlength{\textwidth}{4.0in}%
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.0in}%

\mdfdefinestyle{MyMarginNoteStyle}{
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}

\newcommand{\MarginNote}[1]{%
\marginpar{%
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyMarginNoteStyle]%
    \textbf{Notes}%
    \par\bigskip%
    #1%
\end{mdframed}%
}}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\MarginNote{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[4-6]
\MarginNote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to typeset your code (cut and pasted into TeXShop) however, I get an error message ! Undefined control sequence.
  l.9 \mdfdefinestyle
                   {MyMarginNoteStyle}{
? Is one of the packages missing in TeX Live 2011?

Comment: @Sony: I just did that now (also with TeXShop and TeXLive 2011) and I did not get that error message. Have you done an update to the packages since installing TeXLive 2011?

Comment: I usually wait a year for the next version to come out. So, I do have to update TeXLive2011.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sony: If you want to use this solution it looks like you'll need and updated version of the `mdframed` package.  Alternatively, you could try placing the style settings that are specified in `MyMarginNoteStyle` as part of the actual `\begin{mdframed}` and remove the `mdfdefinestyle{MyMarginNoteStyle}{...}` section.

Comment: @sony I have the same issue. By all accounts an upgrade will fix it. I'll be able to confirm this tonight.

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks.  I did upgrade after seeing Peter's comment.  It works now.